# N-dimensional Cooley-Tukey FFT

Tags: fft

I am trying to formulate an n-dimension algorithm for the Cooley-Tukey FFT. In two dimensions, it is very clear:

$$ 
Y[k_1 + k_2 n_1] = \sum_{l_2 = 0}^{n_2} \Biggl[ \Biggl( \sum_{l_1 = 0}^{n_1 - 1} X \left[l_1 n_2 + l_2 \right] \omega_{n_1}^{l_2 k_1}\Biggl)\omega_n^{l_2 k_1}\Biggl]\omega_{n_2}^{l_2 k_2}
$$

Here is a link on more documentation on this formula: [Implementing FFTs in Practice](https://cnx.org/contents/ulXtQbN7@15/Implementing-FFTs-in-Practice)

In the case of 3 dimensions, how would this formula change? So if in the previous example we had $$ N = n_1 * n_2$$

How could I write the formula for $$ N = n_1 * ( n_2 *n_3 )$$

and in the case of n dimensions, how could I general the summations? I am having trouble understanding how the twiddle factors get accounted for.